# Linux-compatible RGB-supporting video capture card

Tags: linux, video-capture

I am looking for a capture card that will capture RGB signal from retro consoles on my desktop machine. The consoles I would be capturing (SNES, PS2 and the likes) have a Scart RGB-able cable and for best video quality I would like to be able to capture the RGB signal as directly as possible.

My operating system is Ubuntu (current LTS version) and I would like to use [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) for streaming and the likes.

Since Scart connectors are rather large, if you suggest a card which accepts a different type of cable that’s fine (but please at least leave a hint on how to connect Scart to the card).

I have ample USB ports (2.0 and 3.0), PCI and PCIE x1 slots available.

In summary:

- RGB-supporting
- Accepts Scart or with an idea how to input from Scart
- Ubuntu and OBS compatible
- USB/PCI/PCIEx1 connected

Bonus would be if VGA input from another PC is also accepted.